# Mapkit overlay starting coordinate from Random coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkpolyline

In my app I'm drawing the polyline overlay on the map with the points starting from the user Locations obtained from the `didUpdateUserLocation:` delegate method.

But for some reason it always starts from Africa.

What could be the reason? Do I have to specify any starting coordinate for the polyline?

```
-(void)drawTheRoute{
    [self.mapViewTrace removeOverlay:self.polyline];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[arrayOfPoint.count];
    int i = 1;
    for (TMPoint *point in arrayOfPoint) {
        coordinates[i] = point.coordinate;
        i++;
    }


    MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:arrayOfPoint.count];
    [self.mapViewTrace addOverlay:polyline];

    self.polyline = polyline;

    self.lineRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:self.polyline];
    self.lineRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.lineRenderer.lineWidth = 5;

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
        TMPoint *point = [[TMPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate withSpeed:userLocation.location.speed];
        [arrayOfPoint addObject:point];
        [self drawTheRoute];
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code.  A polyline has to start somewhere so how are you setting its first coordinate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `drawTheRoute` method, the C array `coordinates` is declared with `arrayOfPoint.count` elements and the `for` loop initializes each index of the C array using `i` as the index variable.

**The problem is that the `i` index variable is initially set to 1 instead of 0.**

The first index of a C array (and `NSArray`s) is index 0 -- not 1.

This leaves the first coordinate of `coordinates` as uninitialized and the memory happened to contain values that were interpreted as the coordinate 0, 0 (and sometimes "random" coordinates).

(The other effect is that when `arrayOfPoint` has only one object, the C array will only have one element with an index of 0.  But since `i` is initialized to 1, the `for` loop will end up setting index 1 (the second element) of the C array even though only one element of memory was allocated and you will be accessing memory not allocated to you which could result in EXC_BAD_ACCESS.)

Change this line:

```
int i = 1;
```

to this:

```
int i = 0;
```

Comment: oh crap silly mistake. Thank u so much didn't get the time to test this but guess that shud b d issue